# Flutter can't able to run the project

Tags: flutter

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

// here is my error

```
Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established.
The following Dart file:
  D:\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\scaffold.dart
...refers, in an import, to the following library:
  package:sampleapp/main.dart
That library is in a package that is not known. Maybe you forgot to mention it in your pubspec.yaml file?
```

When i try to run the project its showing this error.I don't have any project like sampleapp also i try to run the project after flutter clean but still i am getting this error

//Here is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: meetdax_d_flutter
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Where i have to mention the package name in this file.I don't know how to solve this issue.I am new to flutter please help to sort out this issue

Comment: Is `sampleapp` mentioned in your `pubspec.yaml` anywhere? I think it would help if you'd add the content of `pubspec.yaml` to your question.

Comment: Anyway this seems an example project. Ain't it? If it's just a project to try flutter. Start over. Type `flutter doctor` from cli and see if thare are any errors. If you have no errors than try to start a brand new project and modify it like the one above. Moreover if this an example project you could post either your full text of `pubspec.yaml` and `main.dart` without regrets ;-]

Comment: i tried to create new project also but i am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your Flutter installation is corrupted.

Run the following commands in the Flutter install directory in a command line shell:

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

Comment: k i will try your suggestion

Comment: when i try to run a command flutter doctor in commandline i am getting an error like Unable to pub upgrade flutter tool

Comment: i sorted my issue.i did uninstall and again reinstalled flutter now its working

Comment: Sounds great. .